# RIGHT package not printing graphs

Tags: r

I'm trying to use the package [RIGHT](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RIGHT/index.html), but my output is not the one shown on the package website (i.e. I can't access the interactive graphics).

```
library(RIGHT)
data(diamonds)
plot(price ~ carat, diamonds, type="p") 
#THE ABOVE WORKS
RIGHT(plot(price ~ carat, diamonds, type="p"))
```

The above just returns a webpage without the graph with "© 2013 - The RIGHT team"
 on the left and "E-mail : right-user@googlegroups.com" on the right. Basically the bottom of the last graph shown [here](https://code.google.com/p/r-interactive-graphics-via-html/wiki/HelloRIGHT).

I've tried to do this in the R console and in Rstudio and got the same output.
I'm running Windows 7 (64 bit), R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25). I've also tried with previous R versions but got the same output. Has this happened to anyone else?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for using RIGHT. If you see a small box and the copyright statement from above statement, you may be experiencing browser compatibility issue. We have not been able to solve browser compatibility issue completely yet, so you probably have to do the following at the moment:

https://code.google.com/p/r-interactive-graphics-via-html/wiki/FAQs